# cannot display struct content

Tags: matlab

I use the [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/regionprops.html) function on a many frames of a video. But on one of the frames regionprops returns a weird struct.

Here is my code. It always fails on the same frame:

```
stats = regionprops(I, 'Centroid');
disp(isfield(stats, 'Centroid'))
disp(fieldnames(stats))
disp(stats.Centroid)
```

It is puzzling, because the [isfield()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isfield.html) function and the [fieldnames()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fieldnames.html) function return with sensible results.

This is an example output when my code doesn't fail:

```
  1

 'Centroid' 

  133.6667  159.6667
```

This is the output when it fails:

```
  1

 'Centroid'

 Error using ==> disp 
 Not enough input arguments.
```

On a side note: I use a pretty old version (`6.1.0.450 (R12.1)`)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the problem.

When the function regionprops doesn't return a struct that is of size 1x1 (more/less than one centroid is found) than disp cannot handle the input.

Changed my code for testing to this:

```
stats = regionprops(I, 'Centroid');
disp(isfield(stats, 'Centroid'))
disp(fieldnames(stats))
disp(size(stats))
```

Output when code doesn't fail:

```
 1

'Centroid'

 1     1
```

Output when code fails:

```
 1

'Centroid'

 0     1
```